# Is "window.onload" required when a script is in the bottom of a page?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given that my js script file in put in the bottom of a page, is "window.onload" in:

```
var elem1;
window.onload = () => {
  elem1 = document.getElementById("element1");
};
```

really needed? As opposed to simply:

```
  var elem1 = document.getElementById("element1");
```

If there's no difference, will this still remain true if I add "async" to it? Namely:

```
  <script async src="...."></script>
```

Comment: No, it's not needed. `window.onload` is used to make sure that the JS runs after all the HTML is loaded. Since the page is loaded in order, everything is loaded when you get to the bottom.

Comment: Async makes no difference, since that makes it run ever later. If the DOM is loaded when it's synchronous, it will still be loaded later.

Comment: It depends on what is in the code. In your situation no.

Comment: @epascarello Why? What can change between the time that the script runs at the bottom and the `load` event occurs?

Comment: Images not fully loaded.

Comment: I recommend using `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');});` as opposed to `window.onload = function() {console.log('page loaded');};`. It's recommended to use one or the other for your sake. It helps prevent executing scripts before all necessary resources are loaded.

Comment: The real question is, is there any downside to placing the code in `window.onload` (or whatever)? Even if your code has fully rendered and you don't have any images to load and you don't need to wait for `async` scripts to load and all of that, what harm is there in running the code in the event handler?

Comment: @HereticMonkey websites without any external resources such as stylesheets and images are probably rare these days. And if you just need to do some DOM manipulation, then why unnecessarily wait for irrelevant stuff to load?

Answer (score 3):

No. The page is loaded from top to bottom in terms of code. If you have your script at the bottom of the page, it will be loaded last, so therefore you don't need window.onload because the page has already been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

`window.onload` is used when you want to execute JavaScript after the HTML is done the parsing. It makes sure all the HTML tags are rendered.

`Async` in script tag is used when you want to execute the JavaScript when the browser is parsing the HTML ( script get executed when available as soon as possible ).

About your question, if there is no difference:

There is a difference between loading the script vs loading a script with async.

The script tag will block the render if you don't use async.